# Construct2 List Creation

Tags: json, game-engine, construct-2

I need to show a list of games a user has assigned to them in Construct2.  I'm brand new to the program and am at a loss at how I can do this.  What I need to do is use the AJAX function to call an external resource; that resource will return JSON, and from that JSON, I need to loop through each and every item and build a representation of the game in a list like so:

```
[Picture]      [Player Name]             [Score]
               [Last Played X]
[Picture]      [Player Name]             [Score]
               [Last Played X]
[Picture]      [Player Name]             [Score]
               [Last Played X]
```

What is the way this would be handled using Construct2 editor?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary and load your json on it.

Construct 2 AJAX doc: https://www.scirra.com/manual/107/ajax

Basically, you can use your AJAX object to make request to an external server or app and then use the tags and the last received data to load on a dictionary previously created.

Construct 2 Dictionary doc: https://www.scirra.com/manual/140/dictionary

The dictionary object has two JSON methods that will allow you to load your JSON information(download and load).

=D